# dnsmasq: Change DHCP range based on group of MAC address

Tags: dhcp, dnsmasq, mac-address

Is it possible to change the DHCP range dnsmasq gives out based on the MAC address block. For example, I want all MACs in the block `00:0C:29` to have a different DHCP range compared to every device on the network.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by creating a tag for the MAC address range and then setting the DHCP drange for that address.

```
dhcp-mac=set:vmware,00:0C:29:*:*:*
dhcp-range=tag:vmware,192.168.32.1,192.168.32.255
```